# Apache Virtual Host URL

Tags: apache, apache2, virtualhost

I made an Apache virtual host for a web application that works fine, but I have a problem with the URL. I want my application to be accessed only using an url similar with: http://ip_address/app_name, but now the aplication can be access also with http://ip_address/.

My virtual host looks like this:

```
NameVirtualHost 192.168.5.235:80

<VirtualHost 192.168.5.235:80>
  ServerName 192.168.5.235
  Alias /ksw "/home/ksw/site"
  DocumentRoot "/home/ksw/site/"
  ErrorLog /home/ksw/logs/error_log
  CustomLog /home/ksw/logs/access_log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Is there a way to configure my application to be accessed only using http://ip_adress/app_name? Thanks.

The home /home/ksw/site files are:

```
drwxrwxr-x 18 apache apache   4096 Aug  4 17:41 .
drwxr-xr-x  4 root   root     4096 Aug  3 20:17 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 apache apache    825 Aug  3 20:18 AdminSettings.sample
-rw-rw-r--  1 apache apache   2179 Aug  3 20:18 api.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 apache apache     28 Aug  3 20:18 api.php5
drwxrwxr-x  2 apache apache   4096 Aug  3 20:17 bin
drwxrwxr-x  2 apache apache   4096 Aug  3 20:18 config
-rw-rw-r--  1 apache apache   4505 Aug  3 20:18 config.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 apache apache  17997 Aug  3 20:17 COPYING
drwxrwxr-x  4 apache apache   4096 Aug  3 20:18 docs
drwxrwxr-x  3 apache apache   4096 Aug  3 20:17 extensions
-rw-rw-r--  1 apache apache    162 Aug  3 20:18 FAQ
-rw-rw-r--  1 apache apache 236945 Aug  3 20:17 HISTORY
drwxrwxr-x  2 apache apache   4096 Aug  3 20:18 home
drwxrwxrwx  3 apache apache   4096 Aug  3 20:17 images
-rw-rw-r--  1 apache apache   2474 Aug  3 20:18 img_auth.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 apache apache     35 Aug  3 20:17 img_auth.php5
drwxrwxr-x  9 apache apache  12288 Aug  4 14:13 includes
-rw-rw-r--  1 apache apache   4561 Aug  3 21:03 index.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 apache apache     32 Aug  3 20:17 index.php5
-rw-rw-r--  1 apache apache   3992 Aug  3 20:17 INSTALL
-rw-rw-r--  1 apache apache   3772 Aug  3 20:18 install-utils.inc
drwxrwxr-x  4 apache apache   4096 Aug  3 20:18 languages
drwxrwxr-x  2 apache apache   4096 Aug  3 20:17 locale
-rw-rw-r--  1 apache apache   4993 Aug  4 14:05 LocalSettings.php
drwxrwxr-x  8 apache apache   4096 Aug  3 20:18 maintenance
-rw-rw-r--  1 apache apache    569 Aug  3 20:18 Makefile
drwxrwxr-x  2 apache apache   4096 Aug  3 20:17 math
-rw-rw-r--  1 apache apache   1532 Aug  3 20:18 opensearch_desc.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 apache apache   6173 Aug  3 20:18 profileinfo.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 apache apache   3535 Aug  3 20:18 README
-rw-rw-r--  1 apache apache    299 Aug  4 17:41 redirect.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 apache apache     35 Aug  3 20:17 redirect.php5
-rw-rw-r--  1 apache apache     91 Aug  3 20:17 redirect.phtml
-rw-rw-r--  1 apache apache  34280 Aug  3 20:17 RELEASE-NOTES
drwxrwxr-x  2 apache apache   4096 Aug  3 20:17 serialized
-rw-rw-r--  1 apache apache  18814 Aug  3 20:18 setup.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 apache apache  20480 Aug  3 20:18 .setup.php.swp
drwxrwxr-x  9 apache apache   4096 Aug  3 20:18 skins
-rw-rw-r--  1 apache apache    603 Aug  3 20:18 StartProfiler.php
drwxrwxr-x  4 apache apache   4096 Aug  3 20:17 t
-rw-rw-r--  1 apache apache  12822 Aug  3 20:18 Test.php
drwxrwxr-x  2 apache apache   4096 Aug  3 20:18 tests
-rw-rw-r--  1 apache apache   2746 Aug  3 20:18 thumb.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 apache apache     32 Aug  3 20:18 thumb.php5
-rw-rw-r--  1 apache apache   1373 Aug  3 20:18 trackback.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 apache apache  13195 Aug  3 20:18 UPGRADE
drwxrwxr-x 16 apache apache   4096 Aug  3 20:18 wiki
-rw-rw-r--  1 apache apache     88 Aug  3 20:17 wiki.phtml
-rw-rw-r--  1 apache apache   3830 Aug  3 20:18 xmlp4.php
```

Answer (score 1):

Captain Obvious says it shouldn't be so. =)
May be only if 'app_name' dir is a symbolic link to 'ip_addr' dir.
Or if you use django (for example) and configured views incorrectly.
Do you use php? If so - something definitely wrong happens=)

---

added:
If you 'app_name' string is actually 'ksw' than...
You've installed you mediawiki in the site root dir and ONLY added a link by 'Alias /ksw' to it!!
Solutions:

- If you want ONLY to restrict access to http://ip_address/ use .htaccess apache file.
- If you want 2 different pages at / and /app_name you need to create folder 'app_name' and install your app there!

That's all.

Comment: Yes I use php. It is actually a version of MediaWiki that I try to make it work.

Comment: What files are in the site root dir (/home/ksw/site/)? Make a list 'ls -la' please.
And the main question I think=)... What do you have instead of 'app_name'??  Is that 'ksw'?

Comment: Yes the app_name is 'ksw'. I updated my question with the listing. Thanks.